# The "Recording" tag - Proper usage?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm not really clear on what the [recording](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recording) tag is used for.  Can someone shed some light on it's current usage, and whether or not we should change it?  It seems somewhat arbitrary at the moment, and there's no tag wiki for it.  Maybe it should just be nuked?

Answer (score 1):

When I used it in [a question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/855/why-did-maverick-records-ask-muse-to-remove-falsetto), it was about the record label(Maverick Records). I believed this was the way the tag should be used. However, I missed the fact that there was also a `record-label` tag! After that, I believe there is no use for the `recording` tag and you're right to nuke it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a community regular, but it makes sense to me to use it for recording techniques like I just did in my question [Non-stylistic reasons for whole-song fade out](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/2214/71).

Comment: Perhaps a recording-techniques tag is in order.  I just think a recording tag is too generic, kinda like having a music tag.